# How to code Multipart-form POST REQUEST using apollo-datasource-rest

Tags: rest, graphql, salesforce, multipartform-data, apollo-server

I want to code the multipart-form POST REQUEST below using `apollo-datasource-rest`

[image]
[image]

My attempt to code this leads to a BAD REQUEST error

```js
const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

class SalesforceApi extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initialize({});

    this.getAccessToken()
      .then((accessToken) => {
        this.headers = {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        };
      });
  }

  async getAccessToken() {
    console.log('Getting Salesforce access token');

    try {
      const response = await this.post(
        'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        {
          username: 'FILTERED@FILTERED',
          password: `${'FILTERED'}`,
          grant_type: 'password',
          client_id: 'FILTERED',
          client_secret: 'FILTERED',
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        },
      );
      const { accessToken } = response;
      console.log(`ChangeGear sessionId: ${accessToken}`);
      return accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`${error}`);
    }
    return 'No access token!!!';
  }


module.exports = SalesforceApi;
```

```
[server:salesforce:local] POST https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token (343ms)
[server:salesforce:local] Error: 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: I don't understand if you want to send the fields as `form-data` or do you also want to send some kind of file with it as _multipart_. To my understanding, _multipart_ is used in forms that traditionally have a file input. In either way, you have to do the form data encoding yourself as apollo is probably only sending over JSON. The second argument [of `post`] is typed as `BodyInit | object` where `BodyInit` is `ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | string`. I am happy to elaborate in an answer if this is really your problem.

Comment: you are totally right, I realised later that multipart was not the problem at all. I was 'misled' by the REST client. In fact, I had to send as query params in the URL and it worked. The answer below seems also interesting. I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves correctly, form data is serialized slightly differently hence why the FormData interface exists. And the `apollo-datasource-rest`'s `this.post` method is just a wrapper around fetch, so something like the below should work.

Instead of passing the body as a JSON object, try something like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'FILTERED@FILTERED');
// ... more append lines for your data

const response = await this.post(
        'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        formData
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        },
      );
```

Comment: Just a note if someone have issue like me. If you got an error like `the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found...`  remove the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` header, because the library already set this header and include a boundary for you.

Comment: Ha, nice! I'm pretty sure the library never used to, but at least now it does! Cheers Andy